# django rest framework setting up a Foreign key dynamically in create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model)
  field1 = CharField(max_length=24)
  capacity = models.IntegerField(default=10)

  def used(self):
      return self.bar_set.count()

  def is_available(self):
      return self.capacity - self.used()

  @staticmethod
  def get_or_create_foo(req_count=0):
      foos = list(Foo.objects.all())
      for foo in foos:
          if foo.available() >= req_count:
              return foo
      else:
          foo = Foo() 
          foo.save()
          return foo

class Bar(models.Model)
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)
  foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Now I have serializers like this:

```
class FooSerializer(models.ModelSerializer)
  class Meta:
      model = models.Foo

class BarSerializer(models.ModelSerializer)
  count = models.IntegerField()
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)
  foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)


  class Meta:
      model = models.Bar

  def create(self, validated_data):
      instance = super(BarSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
      instance.foo = Foo.get_or_create_foo(validated_data['count'])
      instance.save()
      return instance
```

Problem is `instance = super(Bar, self).create(validated_data)` at this line I get and exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webmaster/prj/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/webmaster/prj/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_bar_foo_id
```

data passed to BarSerializer is like this (notice no foo is sent here, since it needs to populated dynamically):

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "field1": "some text"
}
```

I guess because call to super creates an instance and save it without FK, because it is not passed in the request and fails there, what is the work around to populate the field `foo` in Bar when its instantiated using the `BarSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about that `super(BarSerializer, self)` call in `create()`, I'd do it like this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = BarSerializer(**validated_data)
    instance.foo = Foo.get_or_create_foo(validated_data['count'])
    instance.save()
    return instance
```